# Spritekit node zRotation doesn't keep aspect ratio of node when child of another node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, aspect-ratio, coordinate-systems

I am building a game and I would like to be able to rotate a node. I can rotate is perfectly fine if the parent of that node is `self` (The GameScene), but if I add the node as a child of another node that doesn't have the same `width x height` ratio, it looses it's aspect ratio.

I thought I could simply find the scene ratio and multiply the node's width by it after changing parent, and this works fine but... When I rotate the node (zRotation), it stretches again. The maximum stretch is when the node is rotated at 90 degrees, as the new parent node is a rectangle that is higher than larger.

I was wondering if there is a way to always keep the aspect ration intact even when rotating and change node parent (coordinate system)?

I simply add nodes to bigRectangle (a big rectangle on the GameScene). It looks stretched on the rectangle (it does not if I add it to the GameScene) so I change the ratio by doing:

```
let myRatio = self.frame.height / self.frame.width
myNode.xScale = 1
myNode.yScale = 1 * myRatio
```

This works but when the node is rotated (zRotation) it becomes stretched again...

I added pictures;

[image: Before rotation, ratio is good]

[image: After rotation, ratio is broken]

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this? I can reproduce children nodes (2 levels or more especially) end up looking really strange when scale and zRotation are applied to each node.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure this on the scene itself:

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

Comment: I tried and this does not work for me. The aspect ratio when put on the scene is perfect and does not change when rotated. The problem is when the parent is another node that doesn't have the same width/height ratio as the scene, then it breaks the ratio. I added some pictures.

Comment: I'm ordering my nodes this way: I have a SKNode Objects a container and add SKSpriteNodes as chips to the container. Is this possible for you?

Comment: I suppose this is a kind of hack, as you place nodes on the container, that could have the same ratio of the scene. This could be a worst case solution. Still, I would like to get a real solution on how to manager aspect ratio on nodes, especially if I want to change the parent on the fly.